# Which is the correct way to write array elements in string?

Tags: php, arrays, string

Consider an array like this:

```
$array = array('a' => 1, 0 => 1);
```

If I'm putting $array['a'] into a string, should I use:

```
"{$array['a']} {$array[0]}"
or
"$array[a] $array[0]"
```

Or it doesn't make any difference? (Note that both strings will print "1 1", they both work the same way)

I want to know which one is more commonly used and why (such as easier readability, faster parsing, etc.). If you write another way, please explain how it is better than the ones I presented.

Comment: @AmitGarg just wondering how `serialize` helps outputting the value at a certain index to a part of a string?

Comment: @dbf: I guess he's thinking "it outputs the text too!"...Albeit, not in the right format, but that's a feature, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
"{$array['a']} {$array[0]}"
```

OR

```
"".$array['a']." ".$array[0].""
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple to have

```
$str = "hello ".$array['a']." what's up?";
```

Answer (score -1):

Neither -- it will be much better for maintainability to use something similar to

```
'{'.$array['a'].'} {'.$array[0].'}'
```

Note that the bracers here are only if you actually want them in your output.

Comment: His curly brackets were to evaluate the value of that array element, I believe.

Comment: Wasn't 100% sure, so added the comment to clarify - some people actually wonder why their bracers are not included in output.

Answer (score -1):

The second option will work *as long as the string inside the key of the array is left unquoted*. Consider explicit concatenation like this to improve on readability:

```
"blah ".$array[0]." blah"
```

(A variant thereof is `"blah", $array[0]," blah"`)

Comment: "Note: To reiterate, inside a double-quoted string, it's valid to not surround array indexes with quotes so "$foo[bar]" is valid. See the above examples for details on why as well as the section on variable parsing in strings." http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Could the cowardly downvoter actually say *why* they've decided to downvote the only two useful/explanative answers on this question?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I guess it's because you wrote incorrect information. "The second option will not work, as PHP does not allow it" - second option works just fine and does the same as the first one.

Comment: @Dalius: that hasn't always been the case. I'll correct - didn't actually know that.